# LINQ Query returns multiple copies of first result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a view defined in the database (archiveContentPreviews), It joins together several tables and in Linq it has one entity key (ArchiveID), I want to query this view with this simple query:

```
        var x = from fields in entities2.archiveContentPreviews
                where fields.ArchiveID == archiveID
                select fields;
        return x.ToList<archiveContentPreview>();
```

The problem that it returns exact number of results but multiple copy of the first result, and when I execute that query in SQL management studio it returns correct results, any help?!

Comment: Capture the SQL being sent using SQL Profiler and post it. It will tell you what EF misunderstood.

Comment: Open *Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Performance Tools > SQL Query Profiler* start profiler and then execute your linq query. Profiler will show which SQL was executed on server

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I honestly was going to tell him "use Google". Your answer was much nicer.

Comment: Got the same problem one day, you must be missing a key (or the "good" key on your entity (even if it's a view, it must have one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This typically happens when the column (or columns) designated as primary key have no unique values in the view. In your case, `ArchiveID` is probably repeated in a large number of view rows (which is also indicated by your `where` clause). You will have to find (or add to the view) a combination of columns that uniquely identify a view row and mark those as primary key in the EF model.

Note that the data returned by the generated SQL query may contain rows with different values (but the same `ArchiveID`), but EF just materializes entity objects for each `ArchiveID` with the first result it can find for that id.

Answer (score 1):

Note a workaround (if you can't specify additional keys -- e.g. for a datatable you don't administer but just read-only access or whatever) is to select the individual columns within the query.

```
var x = from fields in entities2.archiveContentPreviews
                where fields.ArchiveID == archiveID
                select new {fields.col1, fields.col2};
        return x.ToList<archiveContentPreview>();
```