# LINQ query with "hashset.contains" method only selects by one element of hashset

Tags: c#, linq

** Found the actual problem that was happening...due to records it wasn't obvious at first this was the case [LINQ Query returns multiple copies of first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811050/linq-query-returns-multiple-copies-of-first-result) **

As the title says, the "pgnIDs.Contains(item.pgn)" part below is only selecting based on the first element of the hashset.  I'd expect it to select a record if "item.pgn" is ANY of the values in pgnIDs.

```
HashSet<string> pgnIDs = new HashSet<string> { "EFFA", "EFFF", "FEE8", "FEE6", "FEF3", "FFF8", "FFFF" };

//...

var innerQ = (db1.can_raw_data_grainquality_2017
                                    .Where(item => item.ref_id == q.ref_id &&
                                    pgnIDs.Contains(item.pgn))
                                    .OrderBy(item => item.ts_sec)
                                    .ThenBy(item => item.ts_usec)
                                    .Select(item => item)).ToList();
```

** update **
I tried with a straight "OR" for two of the values in the hashset and LINQ still only selected based on one of them.  Is this behavior expected? Either one of the values below will work alone (in that records will be found).

```
                    var innerQ = (db1.can_raw_data_grainquality_2017
                            .Where(item => item.ref_id == 29225 &&
                            (item.pgn == "FFF8" || item.pgn == "EFFA"))
                            .OrderBy(item => item.ts_sec)
                            .ThenBy(item => item.ts_usec)
                            .Select(item => item.pgn)).ToList();
```

Per Ivan's comment (thanks!) I got the raw SQL query out and even tried it in SSMS.  It did in fact work as expected in SSMS/raw SQL???

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[pgn] AS [pgn]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[ts_sec] AS [ts_sec], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[ts_usec] AS [ts_usec], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[channel] AS [channel], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[mid] AS [mid], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[pgn] AS [pgn], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[sa] AS [sa], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[dlc] AS [dlc], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d0] AS [d0], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d1] AS [d1], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d2] AS [d2], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d3] AS [d3], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d4] AS [d4], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d5] AS [d5], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d6] AS [d6], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[d7] AS [d7], 
    [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017].[ref_id] AS [ref_id]
    FROM [dbo].[can_raw_data_grainquality_2017] AS [can_raw_data_grainquality_2017]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (29225 = [Extent1].[ref_id]) AND ([Extent1].[pgn] IN (N'FFF8',N'EFFA'))
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[ts_sec] ASC, [Extent1].[ts_usec]
```

Comment: Your expectations are the same as mine. Are you sure it isn't the id check that is filtering things out?

Comment: @Chris no -- i already verified this straight in SQL (SSMS) that the records with that ref_ID contain multiple of the values in pgnIDs.

Comment: I thought you probably would have confirmed that but its always worth asking. Sadly that is the only thing I can think of that might have caused that issue so I have no more suggestions. :(

Comment: @Chris thanks -- based on your thoughts though I did try a straight "OR" and it still behaved that way.  Either one of the values will work alone but it only selects one when both are there.

Comment: Neither is expected. What is the type of `db1.can_raw_data_grainquality_2017`? Are you 100% sure either one alone works?

Comment: @IvanStoev db1.can_raw_data_grainquality_2017 is a dbcontext (EF6).  If i just use a single one of those values (either one) I get records back.  SO yes 100% sure they work alone.

Comment: Sounds weird. Could you post the generated SQL query (to get it, replace `ToList()` with `ToString()`). Ah, and is `can_raw_data_grainquality_2017` mapped db table or **view**?

Comment: @IvanStoev did not know about that, thanks!  I posted it -- and also tried it in SSMS and it worked??!!  What the heck is going on here???

Comment: It sounds like EF query result materialization issue. Which is known to happen with non properly mapped database views.

Comment: @IvanStoev OK i found a "bug" in my code from troubleshooting which stemmed from getting the raw SQL query.  Thanks for that!  I think it will work now.  Sorry!

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)